# TSQL Trigger on Create

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, count

I need some help creating a trigger to perform the following.

**Tables**

1. UserGroup
2. User

Everytime I create a new User record I populate a foriegn key field called UserGroupId which links the User to a UserGroup. What I want to achieve is to update a Count field called TotalUsers on the UserGroup table.

Please any help will be great as I am new to TSQL triggers. Thanks

Comment: Look at this MSDN note on how to create a trigger and then you just need to plug in your update query on insert of new record. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Quite honestly: I wouldn't compute **and store** that number of users - I would only compute it (e.g. in a view) when you need it - but don't store it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with marc_s that this kind of info might be better to fetch only when necessary instead of storing it in a separate field in the table. But here's a trigger that should do what you want:

```
create trigger UpdateUserCount on [User]
for insert, update, delete
as
begin
    update UserGroup set TotalUsers = sub.UserCount
    from (
        select UserGroupId, COUNT(*) as UserCount
        from [User]
        where UserGroupId in (
            select UserGroupId from inserted
            union
            select UserGroupId from deleted
        )
        group by UserGroupId
    ) as sub
    where UserGroup.UserGroupId = sub.UserGroupId
end
```

This trigger updates the count also when you delete a user or when you update the group on a user. I have assumed that the primary key column in the UserGroup table is called UserGroupId.